# find no of repeated column and saved as rank in sql query

Tags: mysql

I have table having 2nd column is in descending order like

```
a 30  
a 28
a 18
a 10
b 40
b 34
c  32
c  22
```

i want a result like

```
a 30  1
a 28  2
a 18  3
a 10  4
b 40  1
b 34  2
c  32  1
c  22  2
```

Thanks..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with variables

```
SET @level:=1;
SET @group='';
SELECT
    column1,
    column2,
    Sort
FROM(
    SELECT 
        column1,
        column2,
        @level :=(IF(@group = column1,@level+1 ,1)) AS `Sort`, 
        @group := column1
    FROM t
ORDER BY column1 ASC, column2 DESC
) AS l;
```

### SQL Fiddle Demo

OUTPUT

```
| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | SORT |
----------------------------
|       a |      30 |    1 |
|       a |      28 |    2 |
|       a |      18 |    3 |
|       a |      10 |    4 |
|       b |      40 |    1 |
|       b |      34 |    2 |
|       c |      32 |    1 |
|       c |      22 |    2 |
```

Comment: i want a third column which give the rank based on 2nd column.

Comment: @user1903114 i have updated the answer according to your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.*, COUNT(*) AS rank
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN 
Table1 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1
AND t1.col2 <= t2.col2
GROUP BY t1.col1, t1.col2
ORDER BY t1.col1, t1.col2 DESC
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/727d9/4)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have mysql installed at the moment but there should be equivalent or even this may work:

```
SELECT 
 a, b, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY a ASC, b DESC) 
FROM test GROUP BY a, b ORDER BY a ASC, b DESC;
```

works fine with postgresql 9.2